# Xamarin Studio Device Log - Clear Old IOS Simulators

Tags: xamarin, xamarin-studio

How do I clear down all the old IOS simulators from the device log drop down -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found it.  Go to -

/Users/YOURUSER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices

OR

~/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices

and wipe out all the old simulator session directorys from there (sort by date modified to make sure you don't delete any useful latest ones).

May have to restart Xamarin Studio to see the effect.